# How to run an existing code on Visual Studio through a simple UI with button using Windows Presentation Foundation?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, user-interface

I have a C# code which I would like to run through a simple button click using WPF. I am not sure how to achieve this since the creation of a WPF solution in Visual Studio already comes with a .cs file.
If I delete the existing namespace, the program wouldn't run, thus, is there any way I can add a second namespace and run it?

Thank you!

I have not tried anything in specific because of my lack of knowledge.

Comment: You dont actually have to do anything significant

Just draw a button to your WPF window and double click on it, it will generate a function for it to be called

Namespace can be changed / added by creating a codefile with namespace definition

Comment: I am not sure of the means you imply. How can I create a codefile first of all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you think things are too complicated. Regarding wpf, you only need to follow the steps below to use the Button trigger method:

1. Right-click your project => Add => New Item, add a Class.

[image]

2. Write a method in the newly created Class:

[image]

```
using System.Windows;

namespace buttonTest
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public void Test()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Test successfully");
        }
    }
}
```

3. Drag a button from the toolbox in MainWindows

[image]

3. Put the mouse on the button, double-click the button when the mouse shows an arrow, and write the previous method to Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

   ```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Class1 class1 = new Class1();
        class1.Test();
    }
   ```

Start wpf, click the button to call the previous method

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that gives me a route to using my existing code!

Answer (score -1):

New WPF projects generate automatically some files that are:
1.App.xaml
2.MainWindow.xaml

'App.xaml' is the first file to be processed when your project is run

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApp2.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
     
</Application.Resources>
```

On line 5, open the file 'MainWindow.xaml'. The program would not run if you deleted 'MainWindow.xaml' or 'App.xaml'.